# Cannot change TextBoxFor width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is a simple html code from my ASP .NET MVC 5 project:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-12", style = "Width:1000px" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

I am trying to get a text box that is wide. However, no matter what I try for the width value, the text box width stays small.

I moved from EditorFor to TextBoxFor hoping I will have better control of width:-(.

Please help me understand what is it that I am missing? Regards.

Comment: You could also try replacing the `style = ""` with `@style = "width:400px;"`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it doesn't help.

Comment: maybe your style overwrite with other thing

Comment: the class "col-md-12" is only for divs, and you are using it on the textbox, maybe that's the problem or you have another style in a css file or in the view

Answer (score 4):

This question has been out there for a while and I stumbled upon it while looking for an answer to the same problem.

It turns out the default VS template comes with a file called Site.css which includes the following style:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

So either change the max-width on this style or override the max-width with another style rule.

Comment: +1. This one had me going insane. Nice catch. This is something you would definitely not expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are using Bootstrap. Try removing classes from the outer divs or even bootstrap completely.